# Нужна база всех населенных пунктов СНГ и ближнего зарубежья. Где найти?

Tags: база-данных, поиск-api

Нужна база всех населенных пунктов СНГ и ближнего зарубежья на русском языке. Где найти?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://vk.com/dev/database

Answer (score 6):

Можно взять [базу данных](https://www.pochta.ru/support/database/ops) почтовых индексов почты России. Эта база обновляется регулярно, но ИВЦ Регистрации почтовых отправлений отдаёт её только в виде текстового файла. О том, как работать с базой, есть хорошая [статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/190122/).

Другой официальный источник - [Федеральная информационно-адресная система](http://wiki.gis-lab.info/w/%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%90%D0%A1) и связанный с ней классификатор адресов ([КЛАДР](http://gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/)), который поддерживает налоговая служба.

Кроме того, сообществом GIS-Lab поддерживается [база данных названий населённых пунктов](http://gis-lab.info/qa/vmap0-settl-rus.html) на основе американской карты VMap0.

Выбор зависит от того, насколько полную базу вы ищете, насколько важна её постоянная актуализация.

Answer (score 0):

Есть у меня такое:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dR-tk8KTN2WWFSVDVjanlHWU0/edit?usp=sharing
```

Все страны СНГ, id Крыма российский)